# Put WAMPSERVER online but hide its server's index file

Tags: localhost, wamp, virtualhost, wampserver, httpd.conf

Currently I'm able to put WAMP online and access all my projects from other devices using the host IP address.

But what displeases me is the fact that even from other devices, the server's index file which shows the list of all the projects is also accessible. What I want is to be only able to view it from local machine, not from others. Others can only access the index files found in the projects not the one on the root server.

I have tried to set some values in httpd.conf files. But not successful. I searched for this issue on the net, but found different ones.

Comment: You can try create an .htaccess file and put there ACL directives.

Could you add details to the requirements:
- what is folders structure you have? where are index files located?
- how do you access the main index file with list of projects and project pages?

Comment: Virtual Hosts is your answer